# Can’t call View#subscribe from inside the destroyed callback

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I got an error and strange behavior inside template.onDestoyed;

I have code for infinite scroll subscribtion (it stored in special subscribtion-template) It work fine, until i switch to another route, and create a new instance of subscriber-template.

Code:

```
  Template.subscriber.onCreated(function() {
        var template = this;
        var skipCount = 0;
        template.autorun(function(c) {
            template.subscribe(template.data.name, skipCount, template.data.user);
            var block = true;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($(document).height()) && block) {
                    block = false;
                    skipCount = skipCount + template.data.count;
                    console.log(template.data);
                    console.log("skip_count is "+skipCount);
                    template.subscribe(template.data.name, skipCount, template.data.user, {
                        onReady: function() {
                            block = true;
                        },
                        onStop: function() {
                            console.log('route switched, subscribtion stopped');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

When i "scroll down" on a page, subscriber work fine, when i go in another page and "scroll down" first i get a data from old subscriber template (what must be destroyed in theory) in first time. In second time (scroll down again) new instance of subscriber starts works normally.

[PIRNT SCREEN CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgJm3.jpg)

What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owch! 
The good guy from meteor forums helped me. 
Actually the problem is in `jquery.scroll` event. It not cleaned up when template is destroyed. (Is it a bug? Or it is normal behavior?). I just needed to unbind the scroll event in `onDestroyed` section.